# Orthonormal set

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $c_{n}$ are Fourier Coefficients of $f$ and $f_{n}$ is an orthonormal set, show that 
$$( \Sigma_{n=1}^{N} c_{n}f_{n},f - \Sigma_{n=1}^{N} c_{n}f_{n}) = 0$$
I know to be orthonormal the inner product must be 0 and the norm must be 1, however, I'm confused on why there's a ",f" in the summation, are they saying to take the inner product of the two and subtract it?

Comment: define some function $f$ (periodic step function, for example) and set some value for $N$ say $2$ and see whether this holds :-)

Comment: Will I need to take the inner product of f and the summation of cnfn , because of the comma there?

Comment: that is right and this term is not in general zero.

Comment: if f is defined to be that sum . then if substituting f for that sum, wouldn't just be the inner product of f with itself subtracted from f which wouldn't come out as zero since inner product of f with itself is 0

Comment: if $f=\sum...$, then $f-\sum..=0$ and $(\sum ... , 0) =0$, isn't it?